# Remove white space from xml node not to attribute value

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

From below imput xml, i should get output xml as described.

Input Xml

```
<BPSResponse>    <Response>      <Code>804</Code>      <Text>TagID value is not genuine.</Text>    </Response>  </BPSResponse>
```

Output Xml

```
<BPSResponse><Response><Code>804</Code><Text>TagID value is not genuine.</Text></Response></BPSResponse>
```

I am creating xml by XElement.

```
var bpsResponseXml = new XElement("BPSResponse");

            for (int i = 0; i < bpsResponseStatusCodes.Count; i++)
            {
                var bpsResponse = BPSResponseDictionary.GetBPSResponse(bpsResponseStatusCodes[i]);

                bpsResponseXml.Add(new XElement("Response",
                                    new XElement("Code", bpsResponse.Code),
                                    new XElement("Text", bpsResponse.Text)));
            }

            var outPutXml = bpsResponseXml.Value;
```

I want output xml as formatted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have to disable the formatting while converting to string. Below is sample code.

```
var bpsResponseXml = new XElement("BPSResponse");         

bpsResponseXml.Add(new XElement("Response",
                                    new XElement("Code", "804"),
                                    new XElement("Text", "TagID value is not genuine")));

var outPutXml = bpsResponseXml.ToString(System.Xml.Linq.SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument()
{
    PreserveWhitespace = false
};
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
string flat = doc.OuterXml;
```